# HAML layout.haml and Sinatra not working with url parameters

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

My index.haml is working fine with, for example:

```
get '/about' do
  haml :about
end
```

But if I try to use a user parameter like:

```
get ':user/add' do
  haml :add_item
end
```

The layout.haml is ignored.

I was trying to get this to work using subdirectories in my view folder like:

/view/contact/add.haml

While it inserts the =yield content, it will not show the layout.haml css styles, etc.

So I thought using subdirectories was the issue and put all my hamls in the base views directory. However it seems that anything using a url parameter like get ':user/add' does not incude the layout.haml regardless. Currently this is a test I did:

**myapp.rb**

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"
require "haml"
require "data_mapper"
require "pony"

get '/' do #works fine
  haml :index
end

get '/:user_id/dashboard' do #recognizes the content but ignores layout.haml                                                                        
  haml :dashboard                                                                                        
end
```

my **layout.haml** looks like this:

**views/layout.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Testing haml and sinatra
    %link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css")  
  %body
    #wrapper
      #header
        %h1 HAML Test Template
        %h2 Made with Sinatra and HAML!

      #navigation
        %h1 Navigation

      #sidebar
        %h1 Sidebar

      #content
        =yield

      #footer
        %p
          This is the footer.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

*I don't know if it matters but I'm using shotgun for development*

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by using the following in layout.haml:

**layout.haml**

Instead of:

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css")
```

Replaced (fixed version):

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css")
```

Works fine! Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, when I view source, it appears that it's trying to access my style.css in the wrong place based on the url parameter ":user_id" like so:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/test/myapp/css/style.css
```

So I need to get it to grab the style sheet form the same place it would if I was hitting 127.0.0.1/about which would look like this in the html source:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/css/style.css
```

In the actual code both stylesheet links are identical, but since I'm in a subdirectory it cannot find the stylesheet **style.css**

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/css/style.css *(exists in public/css/style.css)*
```

-vs-

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/test/myapp/css/style.css *(doesn't exist)*
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still seeing an issue now with url parameters using a variable in the url path with sinatra and Haml.

When using these I am seeing the css becoming embedded into the post processed html instead of creating a link to the style.css file. The processed html is as follows (even the doctype is messed up and title isn't included):

I see this now with url parameters in the path (e.g. localhost:4567/user/add):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body { text-align:center;font-family:helvetica,arial;font-size:22px;
    color:#888;margin:20px}
  #c {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:left}
  </style>
</head>
```

Instead of this (e.g. localhost:4567/about):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test app</title>
    <link href='/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  </head>
```

**What am I missing here??**

Comment: Fixed, was an incorrectly named haml file at fault. Should have been views/user/add.haml and I named it views/user/add_user.haml